# How to create individual HTML publish pages using loop through excel spreadsheet

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to create individual HTML pages using a loop function on an excel spreadsheet. I had been manually publishing each page but I have thousands of entries, so I need an automated method using macro. I recorded a macro with the steps I use through the manual approach shown below:

```
Sub HTMLexport()

Columns("A:W").Select
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
    "C:\Users\<user_name>\Desktop\Excel2HTML\Articles\1045_VSE.htm", _
    "Sheet1", "$A:$W", xlHtmlStatic, _
    "FileName_10067", "")
    .Publish (True)
End With
Columns("W:W").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Ultimately what I want is to be able to have Column A and the next column selected (ex. B, C, H, Etc), then have those two published into an HTML page. The name of the file I would like to be based on a cell reference. Ex. Cell W3 would have a value of 1045, and the file name be saved as 1045_VSE.htm, where _VSE is constant through the loop process. That way, each new HTML page name would increment based on the cell reference. Once the HTML page is saved, hide the column and move to the next one, rinse and repeat. Any help with this would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly straightforward to put inside a loop.

Here is an example. I assume that the filename will come from the first row/second column in the sub-range, you can easily modify this, or ask me how and I can revise.  I also assume that the Div ID ("FileName_100067") is constant. Again, this can easily be modified if needed.

```
Sub HTMLinLoop()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim rng As Range '##  The full range including all columns'
Dim subRng As Range '## a variable to contain each publishObjects range'
Dim pObj As PublishObject '## A variable to contain each publishObject as we create it.'
Dim p As Long '## use this integer to iterate over the columns in rng'
Dim fileName As String '## represents just the file name to export'
Dim fullFileName As String '## the full file path for each export'
Dim divName As String '## variable for the DivID argument, assume static for now'

Set rng = ws.Range("A3:W30") '## modify as needed'

For p = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    'Identify the sub-range to use for this HTML export:'
    ' this will create ranges like "A:B", then "A:C", then "A:D", etc.'
    Set subRng = Range(rng.Columns(1).Address, rng.Columns(p + 1).Address)

    'Create the filename:'
    '## modify as needed, probably using a range offset.'
    fileName = subRng.Cells(1, 2).Value & "_VSE.htm"

    'Concatenate the filename & path:'
    '## modify as needed.'
    exportFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & fileName

    'Create hte DIV ID:'
    divName = "FileName_10067" '## modify as needed, probably using a range offset.'

    '## Now, create the publish object with the above arguments:'
    Set pObj = wb.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        fileName:=exportFileName, _
        Sheet:=ws.Name, _
        Source:=subRng.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic, _
        DivID:=divName, _
        Title:="")

    '## Finally, publish it!'
    pObj.Publish

    '## Hide the last column:'
    rng.Columns(p+1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: THanks David for the reply, Ive played around with this and its almost there. The issue I am seeing immediately is that Column A is being hidden after the first loop iteration. Column A is a header column and all the columns afterwards contain information relating to that header. For example, (COLUMN A) Product Name  (COLUMNS B through X) Different Products. So how would I keep Column A from becoming Hidden, and still have the loop complete?

Comment: I tried adding a function after the subRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
by adding 
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

The problem is that Column A is not the starting reference point for the next column, currently the HTML outputs are columns A:B, C:D, E:F when I need it to be A:B, A:C, A:D, A:E, etc. I hope what I am saying makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what column(s) you want to hide. Let me know and I can revise. I have revised to make the ranges like `A:B`, then the next will be `A:C`, and `A:D`, etc.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. In the instance where the range is A:B, Column B gets hidden after its published and the HTML file is created, and A stays, A:C will have C hide after publishing and so on. The reason for this is there is a JPEG in the 1st row and 1st column that spans the range A:B, when the HTML page publishes the JPEG is at the top of the HTML page with the information below it. The only way i knew how to make the HTML page show the image is through this way.

Comment: try changing the line that says `subRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True` to this: `rng.Columns(p+1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True`.  This should hide the *last* column in the range, so for range `A:B` it will hide `B`, for range `A:C` it will hide `C` (`B` already hidden in the preceding iteration), etc.

Comment: David, its almost there, the first HTML page comes out correctly. After that it takes a second column as well as the intended one. Ex. A:B come out right, but then A:C+D, A:E+F, etc. Ive played around with the p variable to figure out the offset issue. Here is what i have the code looking like now, see code above, i edited it to reflect what code i am using now.

Comment: I think the `p` variable is correct, but try removing the `step 2`. that was a remnant from my first attempt assuming you wanted ranges like `A:B`, then `C:D`. Instead of incrementing by 1, it's stepping 2 at a time, so the range you're getting is `A:B` (correct), then `A:D` (with column `B` hidden).  If you remove the `step 2` it should give you `A:C` and (with `B` hidden), then `A:D` (with `B:C` hidden), etc.

Comment: That did it! Its beautiful, Thanks a lot David!!

Comment: I have accepted,
Question on the side, the output HTML file retain the previous columns information (even though its not visible). And therefore, each new HTML page increases in size. Is there a way to prevent this? Is there a way to alter the code so it only selects the two columns by themselves instead of the range?

Comment: Only reason i ask is because after exporting 2100 HTML pages, they total around 1GB worth of data, which is not what I would call light weight for what it is.

Comment: I think the issue is that HTML doesn't know what to do with a "hidden" column. You could probably rework this to copy only the visible range to a new/temporary file, set the `PublishObject` in that file, publish it, and then remove/delete the temporary file.  That way they would all contain only the 2 columns, and would not contain the hidden columns.

Comment: I tried using a pObj.Delete statement but that didnt seem to do the trick

Comment: You would simply create a new Workbook (e.g., Dim wbNew as Workbook: Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add), copy the TWO columns in to that `wbNew.Sheets(1)`, create the `PublishObject` from that data, and then  do `wbNew.Close` without saving. Probably have to do `Application.DisplayAlerts=False` before the `.Close` and then turn them back on `Application.DisplayAlerts=True` after.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found a method where I changed the code into a DO loop until the file name reference cell is empty and it just deletes the 2nd column. Only caveat to such a sloppy code method is you cant save the spreadsheet once the data has been extracted because then the data is gone. Normally I would spend more time doing it right but being that I am in a time crunch it will have to do. I really appreciate all your help.